# Aspnet Angular SPA template not working after updating to angular 5

Tags: asp.net, angular, .net-core, spa-template

I have updated aspnet JavaScriptServices angular template to Angular 5.0.2

everything looks fine but when it published i'm getting following error

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
An unhandled exception has occurred: No ResourceLoader implementation has been provided. Can't read the url "app.component.html"
Error: No ResourceLoader implementation has been provided. Can't read the url "app.component.html" at Object.get
```

If I turn off the server side prerendering, by removing `asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server"` then it will work fine without any issues.

Any ideas on this?

**Note: I have done the changes to use `AngularCompilerPlugin` instead of `AotPlugin`as well**